# Passing Complex Filter throw HttpApi in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, httpapi

I've build an Asp.Net Core Controller and I would like to pass Data throw the Url to my Backend.

Throw my URI I would like to paste: filter:"[[{"field":"firstName","operator":"eq","value":"Jan"}]]

So my URI looks like: https://localhost:5001/Patient?filter=%5B%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22firstName%22,%22operator%22%3A%22eq%22,%22value%22%3A%22Jan%22%7D%5D%5D

and my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<bool> Get(
    [FromQuery] List<List<FilterObject>> filter = null)
{
            return true;
}
```

and my FilterObject looks like:

```
public class FilterObject
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; } = FilterOperator.Eq;

    }
```

The Problem now is that my Data from the URL is not deserialized in my filter Parameter.

Do anyone have an Idea?
Thans for helping.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Throw my URI I would like to paste: filter:"[[{"field":"firstName","operator":"eq","value":"Jan"}]]

You can achieve the requirement by implementing a custom model binder, the following code snippet is for your reference.

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // ...
        // implement it based on your actual requirement
        // code logic here
        // ...

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
        options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase));

        var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<FilterObject>>>(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filter").FirstOrDefault(), options);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<bool> Get([FromQuery][ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]List<List<FilterObject>> filter = null)
{
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! 

A point here: it fails by sending null, so I edited the BindModelAsync in the CustomModelBinder like this:

Comment: ...if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filter").FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<FilterObject>>>(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("filter").FirstOrDefault(), options);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
            else
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(null);